# Using addQueueNames on SimpleMessageListenerContainer takes more time

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, consumer, spring-rabbit

We use SimpleMessageListenerContainer with (max) consumer count as 75. We have a use case, where we need to dynamically subscribe and un-subscribe from some queues, so we use addQueueNames() and removeQueueNames(). When the consumer count is at 75, addQueueNames() method takes around 15 secs to complete. We have around 200 queues currently. We wanted to add and remove queues from listener very often, so do we have any other way to reduce this time?

Answer (score 1):

When queues are added or removed, currently, we have to cancel the current consumers and re-consume from the new list of queues.

The feature was not really designed for rapid changes to the queue list, especially with a large number of queues like that.

You will probably find things are a little more performant if you use a number of containers, each with a subset of the total queue list, to avoid churning all the consumers for each change.

For 2.0 (next year, but we'll probably have a milestone out in the fall) we are planning a complete rewrite of the listener container to take advantage of some changes in the rabbitmq client library [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37764309/how-to-disable-rabbitmq-prefetch-count-with-simplemessagelistenercontainer/37771689#37771689) and the [associated JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-418) for some more information.

We could probably make altering the queue list more efficient as part of that rewrite; feel free to add a comment to the JIRA so we don't forget.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell. I commented on the Jira issue.

Comment: 2.0.0.M2 (milestone 2) is available now; M3 will be released next week the final release will be in the summer (currently June).